# Slidetoggle next using on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidetoggle

I have multiples of these on the page and I'd like to only slidetoggle "comments-box" within each area (ie: the first one it finds).

```
<div class="comments">
<a style="cursor:pointer" onclick="jQuery('.comments-box').slideToggle();">comments</a></span>
        <div class="add-comment">add</div>
        <div class="response-form"></div>
        <div class="comments-box">
         a bunch of comments
        </div>
</div>
```

However, that obviously toggles EVERY "comments-box".

I've tried `onclick="jQuery($(this).next('.comments-box')).slideToggle();"` but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the markup, remove the inline javascript, and add a href to the anchor:

```
<div class="comments">
    <span><a href="#">comments</a></span>
    <div class="add-comment">add</div>
    <div class="response-form"></div>
    <div class="comments-box">
         a bunch of comments
    </div>
</div>
```

Then do this to make each comment-box slide up and down:

```
$(function() {
    $('.comments a').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('.comments').find('.comments-box').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

**EDIT:**

doing it inline :

```
<a onclick="jQuery(this).closest('.comments').find('.comments-box').slideToggle();">comments</a>
```

Comment: Thanks @adeneo - so no way of doing it inline with the `onclick`?

Comment: Of course there is, but why use inline javascript when it's so easily avoided?

Comment: PS. `onclick="jQuery(this).siblings('.comments-box').slideToggle();"` doesn't work

Comment: What is the closing span for, are the elements siblings, like in the code in the answer above, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Only thing wrapped in a span is the anchor

Comment: And that's the problem right there, the wrapping span is missing in your code, only the closing span is there, and that's why the answer doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this'

```
$('.comments a').on("click",function(){
        $(this).parent().find('.comments-box').slideToggle();

        });
```

[**FIDDLE Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dubeynee/PgzrU/59/)

Comment: Thanks, the idea though was using it within an onclick :)

Comment: but this will toggle all the `comments-box`, noting that OP has all those divs and anchor tags in one parent.

Comment: No it will toggle only `a` clicked `comment box`. that is tested

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `siblings()`.
Try this

```
$(function() {
    $('.comments a').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().siblings('.comments-box').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

[**JSfiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/HqAgr/)